# Django-ajax-validation: Validate form fields on click of specified button with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I've managed to get [Django-ajax-validation](https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation/blob/master/docs/usage.txt) (version 1.3) work in my project by setting the `focusout` event in the script of the template with my form as follows:

```
$('#ajax_validated_form').validate('{% url contact_form_validate %}', {type: 'ul', event: 'focusout'});
```

This validates each field of my form via ajax each time I focus out of any input field of the form(click on something else after I've clicked the input).

However, **I would only like to validate when I click on a `<button id="ajax_submit">Ajax submit</button>` element**.

So I tried the following:

```
$('#ajax_validated_form').validate('{% url validate_entity %}', {type: 'ul', event: $("#ajax_submit").on("click")});
```

But this doesn't work. How am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to specify the element I wanted to couple the event to via the value of the dom key (`dom: $("#ajax_submit")`) in the object passed as second argument to the validate method.

So what I needed was the following:

```
$('#ajax_validated_form').validate('{% url validate_entity %}', {type: 'ul', dom: $("#ajax_submit"), event: "click"});
```

### Edit:

Also know that the `#ajax_validated_form` doesn't necessarily have to refer to a `form` element to let the validation work, it works just as well if the form inputs where contained inside a `div`!

E.g.:

```
<div id="ajax_validated_form">
    {{ ajax_val_form }}
</div>
```

works just as well as

```
<form id="ajax_validated_form" action="" method="post">
    {{ ajax_val_form }}
</form>
```

### Edit 2:

Don't forget to include the following (from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)) in the script of your page:

```
    /// To enable Ajax calls with csrf_token protection ///////////////////
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
                // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
                // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
                // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```